# How to pipe sorted results to grep?

Tags: linux

```
$ grep HxH 20170213.csv | awk -F',' '{print $13}' | cut -b 25-27 | sort -u
868
881
896
904
913
914
918
919
920
```

Question> How to pipe the sorted results and feed into `grep`?

Now I have to do the following command manually.

```
grep 868 /tmp/aaa/*.csv
grep 881 /tmp/aaa/*.csv
...
grep 920 /tmp/aaa/*.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your output is numeric (output lines do not contain spaces), you can use a `for` loop with command substitution:

```
for id in $(grep HxH 20170213.csv | awk -F',' '{print $13}' \
            | cut -b 25-27 | sort -u); do
    grep $id /tmp/aaa/*.csv
done
```

Another option is to use `xargs`:

```
grep HxH 20170213.csv | awk -F',' '{print $13}' | cut -b 25-27 | sort -u \
    | xargs -n1 grep /tmp/aaa/*.csv -e
```

The `xargs` variant requires one to jump through a couple hoops to get right:

- by default `xargs` would stick more than one pattern to the same `grep`, which is prevented using `-n1`;
- `xargs` specifies the stdin contents as the *last* argument in the command line, which is a problem because `grep` expects pattern then file name. Fortunately, `grep PATTERN FILES...` can be spelled as `grep FILES... -e PATTERN`, which is why `grep` must be followed by `-e`.

Comment: @q0987 That's what it's for. Off topic.

Comment: @q0987 Yes, but it's a bit more involved because it requires specific options to both `xargs` and `grep`. I've now added an `xargs` variant, but I don't like it because it's harder to understand and (later) modify.

Comment: you can also use the `grep` command more normally by using the `-I {}` command to `xargs` as in: `... | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} /tmp/aaa/*.csv`